# IOS textView delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have created a `UITextView *mytextview` . I want to get event when click textview before `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` delegate.

Now, When I click textview, is's call `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`. After that, it's call `- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView`, it's not good!

I want to `mytextview delegate` was called before call `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`

How to I can resolve this problem

Comment: use `- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView`

Answer (score 0):

Use `textViewShouldBeginEditing` provided by the `UITextViewDelegate`, call your delegate method in it, and return `YES` from this method to let user edit the text.

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [yourDelegate yourMethod:textView];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of Event execution are

1. UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
2. textViewDidBeginEditing

Now  as per our requirement I Fire On Notification that is called when KeyBoardWillShow.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textViewDidBeginEditing:)name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil]
```

And in the selector I passed same function which is called after UIKeyBoardWillShown, Also you can set your Own Function, which you want to do Before UIKeyBoardShow

This is My Code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textViewDidBeginEditing:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    }

    - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
        NSLog(@"textViewDidBeginEditing");
    }
```